# Google maps search API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can someone tell me if is possible in google maps search api, when you search city name in your own language, to return the city name always in english?

So lets say you type city name in russian, but you want to return city name in english language

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm assuming there is a Google Translate API that you could use tho. Could be totally wrong tho.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, I think this is doable using a workaround. For example, you are searching for **"St. Petersburg"** *(a city in Russia)*. The Russian name of that city would be **"Санкт-Петербург"** as per **[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/St.%20Petersburg)**.

Using **[Google Maps Javascript API Places search box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)**, you can log the value of variable **places**. With this, you can now see the returned results once the event **"places_changed"** has been fired.

Here's a sample result:

```
"result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Saint Petersburg",
            "short_name" : "Saint Petersburg",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Saint Petersburg",
            "short_name" : "Saint Petersburg",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Russia",
            "short_name" : "RU",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eSaint Petersburg\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eRussia\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "Saint Petersburg, Russia"
...
}
```

You will notice these properties: "address_components" and "formatted_address" has address that is in english language.

If you are concerned about the address in your searchbox not in english language, you can change it by parsing the address_components key/values or by formatted_address and then setting it as value of the searchbox.

Sample implementation:

```
document.getElementById('pac-input').value = places[0].formatted_address;
```

Working demo below:

```js
      // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
      // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
      // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

      // This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

      function initAutocomplete() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
          console.log(places);
          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }
          document.getElementById('pac-input').value = places[0].formatted_address;
          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }
```

```css
#map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
```

```html
 <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
 <div id="map"></div>
     <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCzjs-bUR6iIl8yGLr60p6-zbdFtRpuXTQ&libraries=places&language=en&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

And that's it. Happy coding and goodluck on your project.